# Update data- attribute on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to write into a div some custom data attributes like these:

```
data-100="50"
```

where "100" is the height of another div and "50" is "height/2". I've done it with jQuery and it works:

```
function customFn() {
var customFn = $('.page-title').height();     
$('#header).attr('data-' + customFn, 'customFn/2');        
}

customFn();
```

Now I want to update that values on window resize, so I've added:

```
$(window).resize(customFn);
```

But I guess that's not the solution because when I resize the window, the function adds new data attributes inside the div with new values instead of updating the existing ones.

Is there an alternative solution for that?

Comment: You should not store information on the name part of the attribute. Why not just use attribute like data-height="100". And you can definately do division (/2) in the code, you don't need to add that to the attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to store information on the name part of the attribute because I am trying to make work [skrollr plugin] (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) for having more control on parallax behaviour. :(

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `attr()` to update data rather use `data()`

```
function customFn() {
    var customFn = $('.page-title').height();     
    $('#header').data(customFn, customFn/2);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you're trying to store two values: height and height/2. You shouldn't store the first one in the name of the data attribute... rather store both in a separate attribute like so:

```
function customFn() {
    var height = $('.page-title').height();     
    $('#header').data('height', height);        
    $('#header').data('half-height', height/2);      
}
```

Even better, since one value is dependent of the other (value1 = value/2), you really only need to store the first one, and can compute the second when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   customFn();
});
```